# mapping object with array of object to angular material mat table in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm trying to display the object array which contain an array inside like

```
users=[
 { username:'xyz@gmail.com',firstname: 'XYZ',lastname:'yz',locations:['A','B','C']}]



<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" mat-sort>  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.username}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

      </table>

      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

I want to show the data in location array .I don't know how to map it.please Help

Comment: How it should looks like in table? like this: A,B,C..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show like A, B, C in table then do like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Locations </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
        <span *ngFor="let loc of row.locations"> {{loc}},</span>
     </td>
</ng-container>
```